# testdriven.io: ValidationError on endpoints /api/open-tasks and /api/closed-tasks from tasks_api service

Tags: fastapi, serverless, pydantic, testdriven.io

Talking about the [Serverless Apps with FastAPI, DynamoDB, and Vue](https://testdriven.io/courses/serverless-fastapi/) course. I'm currently stuck on section "API" from Part 1, which seems to be pydantic related.

When running the tests with `$ poetry run pytest tests.py` a `ValidationError` rises with the following:

```
>   ???
E   pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for APITaskList
E   results -> 0
E     value is not a valid dict (type=type_error.dict)

pydantic/main.py:341: ValidationError
============================================= short test summary info ============================
FAILED tests.py::test_list_open_tasks - pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for APITaskList
```

I was expecting a succesful execution, since I've reproduced all of the course steps accordingly. But anyways, here are some extra info that might help:

- Failing command (from tests.py): `response = client.get("/api/open-tasks", headers={"Authorization": id_token})` - where client is a `TestClient` fixtture.
- Api route ("api/open-tasks"):

```
@app.get("/api/open-tasks", response_model=APITaskList)
def open_tasks(
    user_email: str = Depends(get_user_email),
    task_store: TaskStore = Depends(get_task_store),
):
    return APITaskList(results=task_store.list_open(owner=user_email))
```

- Pydatinc `APITaskList` schema:

```
class APITaskList(BaseModel):
    results: list[APITask]

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
```

- Pydantic `APITask` schema:

```
class APITask(BaseModel):
    id: UUID
    title: str
    status: TaskStatus
    owner: str

    class Config:
        orm_mode: True
```

Comment: One error might be that you have `orm_mode: True` instead of `orm_mode = True` in `APITask.Config`. If that doesn't resolve anything, we need to see `TaskStore`, and especially its `list_open` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out on [@M.O.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11612918/m-o)'s comment:

> ... you have `orm_mode: True` instead of `orm_mode = True` in `APITask.Config`.

Test passed successfully after this fix.